# SSH connection not possible in local network

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

Today I realized a very strange thing:

I have a server (running Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS) in my local network whose SSH port is accessible via the internet (I can connect to it using `ssh my.internet.ip.address`).

However, I realized only today that I cannot connect to it in the local network (`ssh its.local.ip.address` fails without errors).

I checked `/etc/hosts.deny` and added my computer explicitely in `/etc/hosts.allow`, but this has not changed anything. Of course, I also tried restarting ssh and the whole server. There are no new updates available.

Local connection fails:

```
myself@my-desktop ~ $ ssh -v its.local.ip.address
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to its.local.ip.address [its.local.ip.address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection closed by its.local.ip.address
myself@my-desktop ~ $
```

However, remote connection works:

```
myself@my-desktop ~ $ ssh -v my.internet.ip.address
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my.internet.ip.address [my.internet.ip.address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myself/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA [... hidden here ...]
debug1: Host 'my.internet.ip.address' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myself/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myself@my.internet.ip.address's password: 
[ ... everything works just fine ... ]
```

What can be the cause of this problem and more important how can I solve it?

Note: Increasing verbosity (`ssh -vvv`) does not show anything in addition at point where both outputs deviate.

Comment: You can also check the server's /var/log/* files for relevant messages.  From what you have shown, it appears to fail at the step where host keys are verified.  Do you have keys for `its.local.ip.address` in ~/.ssh/known_hosts?

Comment: I looked into `/var/log/auth.log` but my unsuccessful connection attempts are not mentioned there. I don't have a key for `its.local.ip.address` in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Have you tried a ping or trace route? Maybe try another protocol like http. You could also run sshd on an alternate port to rule out filtering of traffic.

Comment: `ping`, `http` and `samba` are working fine (however, `http` is very slow?...). `traceroute` says that I reach my target with the first hop. `iptables` is not doing anything strange (just standard settings) and there is no other firewall installed. I cannot try changing the ssh port, since the server is used by a lot of people (thats why it is reachable from the internet).

Comment: have you figured out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is deciding to drop the connection, so you'd have to debug the problem from the server side. If you have "root" access on the server, you can run `sshd` interactively:

```
/path/to/sshd -ddd -p 42
```

This will launch a copy of `sshd` listening on port 42--you could specify a different number--in debug mode. It will run in the foreground, accepting a single connection and printing debugging information to your terminal.

Now connect with your client:

```
ssh -v -p 42 its.local.ip.address
```

With any luck, the server-side debugging messages should indicate why it's dropping the session.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the client machine is the same in both captures (even though promts differ)
As it is allowing the TCP connection, probably it is related to reverse DNS and/or deny policies on the sshd config.

Try turning off DNS on the server side (UseDNS=no on sshd_config) and restarting sshd (kill -1 should suffice)

Answer (score 0):

This bug is reported to have affected multiply users.

When local, try ssh -X to disable x forwarding.

Also, Maximum Transmission Unit[MTU] may need to be adjusted to the MTU of the ssh_server.

** if that doesn't work when local, try:

```
 myself@my-desktop ~ $ ssh -v my.internet.ip.address
```

If it can traverse out of you network, then back in...

It could be server configuration errors, check sshd_config for "allowed users", as well as where known_host would be stored, add a local.ip.address version of the user "myself."

a copy of sshd could help